# position absolute in react native

Tags: react-native, position, styling

[click to see design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDHo5.png)

I'm having a problem positioning the white floating button on top of the blue header. The button is a TouchableOpacity inside a View which has Header and a ScrollView. How do I position the button on top of the blue header and scrollview?

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Header headerText={'Events'} />
        <TouchableOpacity 
                style={styles.addButtonContainerStyle}
                onPress={ () => {Actions.addEventMain()} }
            >
            <Text style={styles.addButtonTextStyle}>+</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <EventList />
    </View>
```

Comment: Sorry for that. Modified my post just now.

Answer (score 0):

Below code would help. Absolute position of views sometimes becomes hard to maintain when code grows. You need to customise below code as per your need.

```
<View style={{ backgroundColor: "blue", flexDirection: "row-reverse" }}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{ alignSelf: "flex-end" }}>
          <Text style={{ justifyContent: "center", fontSize: 20, textAlign: 'center' }}>
            +
        </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity >
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Text style={{ alignSelf: "center", fontSize: 20, textAlign: 'center' }}>
            Event
        </Text>
        </View>
      </View >
```